# When using dask local, I get "ERROR - Workers don't have promised key"

Tags: python, jupyter, distributed, dask

I have a jumper notebook configured to use the dask local distributed scheduler

```py
#Start Dask
client = Client(
    n_workers=6, 
    threads_per_worker=4,
    memory_limit='8GB',
    processes=True, 
)

client
```

When I start using a dask dataframe I get red error output that contains `ERROR - Workers don't have promised key` searching for this error leads to help with remote clusters.

What is wrong/going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after searching for hours this is what I figured out.

My hostname was not resolvable, due to connecting via VPN my hostname had become unresolvable dask uses your hostname and not localhost for local clusters. ipyparallel has a similar issue but had slightly better errors. That's how I determined the issue.

To get past this on a Mac (or BSD Flavored Unix) set `interface='lo0'` when initializing the cluster.

Comment: You can specify host, port, and many other parameters https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/local-cluster.html#api